# stuck on print and return

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, return

```
def isItEven2(n):

    if (n%2 == 0):
      print('true it is even')
    else:
      print('false it is not even')

def isInCenter2(n):

      if (n>100):
        print('true it is center')
      else:
        print('false it is not center')

def seatLocation2(n):

    if isItEven2(n) and not isInCenter2(n):
          print 'check1'
          return "Right"
    elif not isItEven2(n) and not isInCenter2(n):
          print 'check2'
          return "Left"
    else:
      return "Center"

def seatLocation3(n):

    if not isInCenter2(n) and isItEven2(n):
        print 'check1'
        return "Right"
    elif not isInCenter2(n) and not isItEven2(n):
        print 'check2'
        return "Left"
    else:
        return "Center"
```

`seatLocation2(n)` and `seatLocation3(n)` are behaving differently, can anyone tell me why the output of seatLocation2(n) and seatLocation3(n) differs? Have really spent many hours to figure it out.

Below is the sample output

Output when calling `seatLocation2(2)`:

```
true it is even
true it is even
false it is not center
check2
```

and output when calling `seatLocation3(2)`:

```
false it is not center    
true it is even 
false it is not center
true it is even
check2
Out[1043]: 'Left'
```

I know I used print so i get None value so it's better to use return to pass a value to other function. All I want is an explanation of the steps followed during execution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations check operator `and` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vital point to understanding the difference in execution of the two `seatLocation` methods is to understand two concepts:

- A method *not* having a return statement will return `None`, which is evaluated as `False` in a condition
- Conditions short circuits if possible. That is if you have `condition1 and condition2`, and `condition1` is negative it will never bother to find out what `condition2` are because the end result will always be negative

OK, in your code the functions will *always* return `None` (or `False` so to speak), so when stepping through `seatLocation2(2)` we get:

- Check `if isItEven2(2) and not isInCenter(2)`

  - It calls `isItEven2(2)` which prints "true it is even"
  - but it returns `None` which is false, so it breaks out of the if
- Check `elif not isItEven2(2) and not isInCenter2(2)`

  - It calls `not isItEven2(2)` which prints "true it is even"
  - but it return `None` which is false, but it is negated (`not`) so it is still possible for if to become `True`
  - it calls `not isInCenter2(2)` which prints "false it is not center"
  - but it returns `None` which is false, but negated (`not`) into true
- so we enter the `if` block

  - print "check2" (and return "Left" which you left out of the sample output)

On the other hand if we follow `seatLocation3(2)` it goes like this:

- Check `if not isInCenter2(2) and isItEven2(2)`

  - Calls `not isInCenter2(2)` which prints "false it is not in center"
  - but returns `None` which is negated, so we have to keep on testing
  - Calls `isItEven2(2)` which prints "true it is even"
  - but returns `None" which is false, and we break out of the if
- Check `elif not isInCenter2(2) and not isItEven2(2)`

  - Calls `not isInCenter2(2)` which prints "false it is not in center"
  - but returns `None` which is negated, so we have to keep on testing
  - Calls `not isItEven2(2)` which prints "true it is even"
  - but returns `None" which is false, and negated into True, so the overall expression is again true
- so we enter the if block again

  - and print "check2", and return "Left"

So they do actually behave the same, meaning that both of your functions returns `None` but since you differ whether you do the `not` on the left or the right, it seems like they are misbehaving. But do to boolean short circuiting when you have something like `False and ...`, the second part will never get executed.

Comment: wow that is  how champion present solution . Many many thanks to you. you made my day .crystal clear . 
just a little basic doubt 
isItEven2(2) prints "true it is even"
and where not isItEven2(2) also prints "true it is even"
but from basic i know not True is equal to False . (so wouldn't not isItEven2(2) leads to false ?)

Comment: @learner, that is the core of your question: You have to separate output from actual return values. You can print whatever, but when you return `None`, and afterwards does the `not None` it becomes true!

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something (`True`/`False`) from the `isItEven2` and `isInCenter2` functions.

```
def isItEven2(n):
    if (n%2 == 0):
      print('true it is even')
      return True
    else:
      print('false it is not even')
      return False
def isInCenter2(n):
  if (n>100):
    print('true it is center')
    return True
  else:
    print('false it is not center')
    return False
```

Comment: I know I used print so i get None value so its better to use return to pass a value to other function. All i want is the step followed during execution

Comment: @learner How are you actually calling the functions? What was the `n`?

Comment: i was calling using seatLocation2(2) or seatLocation2(101) anything like this

Answer (score 0):

When you return None from a function it will be interpreted as False. In your case irrespective of the value of 'n', second condition of functions 'seatlocation2(n)' and seatlocation3(n) will be executed as you are taking not of both 'isItEven' and 'isItCenter'. This should suffice in explaining the code flow.

The code flow will precisely follow these steps:

1. Function seatlocation2(n) is called
2. It calls isItEven() function in the if condition which turns out to be False (because of none) and hence the condition does not get executed.
3. It goes to elif block where it takes 'not' of isItEven() which converts the 'False' return value to 'True'; then it calls isInCenter() which returns False; 'not' of which is True. 'And' of both is true. This causes the second condition to always execute as your function always return None.

All other condition are obsolete with the current logical flow

Comment: why i am getting the result that is associated with other function (as i didnt use return in those function) if i am getting None in the seatLoaction function

Comment: As I said second condition will be always true hence check2 will be printed. I hope that is clear. Now when you call those functions (inItEven, isInCenter) from a condition they get called and instructions inside them (print statements) get executed. That's why you see output from them

Comment: You are getting the print 'true it is even' twice because the function 'isItEven()' gets called twice. First in the if condition and then in the elif. Entire 'isItEven()' executes and hence all those prints. Now you might ask why isItCenter() function doesn't gets called twice. It because in the if condition, 'isItEven()' returns False so it doesn't check the next part of 'and' (because the and is false even if one is false). Hence it gets executed only once in the second condition

Comment: Yes all clear but a little bit doubt 
if i try to execute 

isItEven2(102) and isInCenter2(102)

the output is 
"true it is even"

while it is true for both case . why this is happening
why "true it is even" and "true it is center" leads to sorting out the latter one .

Comment: Understand the behaviour of statements connected with 'and'. When the statement on the left of 'and' is False the condition on the right doesn't get executed. You can see that in the call to 'seatlocation2(n)' function. The seatlocation3(n) demonstrates the other side of the picture. Because the condition on the left is 'True' (due to not of none), you get prints from both 'isItEven' and 'isInCenter'. Since they are b eing called in two separate conditions (if and elif), each of them occur twice before second condition becomes true and stops execution of further conditions. hope it clears all

Comment: I think my explanation of how and works explains the output you are getting

Comment: isItEven2(102)
true it is even


isInCenter2(102)
true it is center


isItEven2(102) and isInCenter2(102)
true it is even


isInCenter2(102) and isItEven2(102)
true it is center

Even if both are true then why only right one is executed always ?

Comment: Which functions are you calling. Tell me your call flow. Is it seatlocation2 or seatlocation3 ?